# RENAME FILE TO ANOTHER FILES NAME PREFIX IN SAME DIRECTORY VISUAL BASIC

Tags: vb.net

Currently I have a code that will erase everything in a directory and place two template files in the said directory, a .dwg and a .jpg file. with button4.click

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.ClickDim path As 

String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer)& "C:\epds\WIP\"
    System.IO.Directory.Delete(path, True)

    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile( _
   "C:\Users\edevault\Documents\temp\temp.dwg", _
   "C:\epds\WIP\temp.dwg", overwrite:=True)

    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile( _
   "C:\Users\edevault\Documents\temp\BX-.jpg", _
   "C:\epds\WIP\BX-.jpg", overwrite:=True)
```

Then I download a .zip file to the C:\epds\WIP\ directory and extract it manually.
What I would like to do is reverse the sequence and download the .zip then erase all in directory except the .zip and place the .dwg and .jpg file in the directory, and also rename the .dwg and .jpg files to the last 6 digits of the .zip file name.

- Example:
- SO123456.zip downloads to C:\epds\WIP\
- button4.click erases all files except SO123456.zip and copies BX-.jpg and temp.dwg into C:\epds\WIP\ from C:\Users\edevault\Documents\temp\ then renames BX-.jpg to BX-123456.jpg and temp.dwg to 123456.dwg

The SO prefix of the SO123456.zip is not needed

Comment: Please do not shout (CAPS is shouting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I was able to make this work:

```
Dim tmpDir As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\epds\WIP\")

Dim subd As IO.DirectoryInfo
Dim old, newf, old2, newf2, old3, newf3 As String
Dim withparts As String
Dim withoutparts As String
Dim zippath, extractpath, zip As String
Dim file As IO.FileInfo

'Button to extract ZIP, delete the ZIP, copy in DWG, BOX label, and CMD templates, and rename them the SO number

Public Sub CopyDWG_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CopyDWG.Click
    zippath = "C:\epds\WIP\"
    extractpath = "C:\epds\WIP\"
    Directory.GetFiles("C:\epds\WIP\")
    For Each Me.file In tmpDir.GetFiles()

    Next


    Try
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(file.FullName, extractpath)
    Catch ex As NullReferenceException
        MsgBox("ZIP Archive not found.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Design Dock")
        Exit Sub
    Catch ex As FileNotFoundException
        MsgBox("ZIP Archive not found.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Design Dock")
        Exit Sub
    Catch ex As InvalidDataException
        MsgBox("ZIP Archive not found.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Design Dock")
        Exit Sub
    End Try


    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(file.FullName)
    For Each Me.subd In tmpDir.GetDirectories()
        withparts = subd.Name
        withoutparts = Replace(withparts, "SO", "")
    Next
    MsgBox("Archive unzipped to: " & subd.FullName, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Design Dock")

    Dim msg, title, response As String
    Dim style As Single


    msg = "Do you want to copy starter files to " & subd.FullName & "?"
    title = "Design Dock"
    style = MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.Question
    response = MsgBox(msg, style, title)



    If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then


        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\TEMP\STARTER.DWG", subd.FullName & "\STARTER.DWG")

        old = subd.FullName & "\STARTER.DWG"
        newf = withoutparts & ".dwg"
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(old, newf)
        Catch ex As IOException
            MsgBox("DWG already exists, nothing copied.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Design Dock")
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(subd.FullName & "\STARTER.DWG")
        End Try

        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\TEMP\BX-.JPG", subd.FullName & "\BX-.JPG")

        old2 = subd.FullName & "\BX-.JPG"
        newf2 = "BX-" & withoutparts & ".JPG"
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(old2, newf2)
        Catch ex As IOException
            MsgBox("Box Label already exists, nothing copied.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Design Dock")
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(subd.FullName & "\BX-.JPG")
        End Try

        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\TEMP\BLANK.CMD", subd.FullName & "\BLANK.CMD")

        old3 = subd.FullName & "\BLANK.CMD"
        newf3 = withoutparts & ".CMD"
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(old3, newf3)




        Catch ex As IOException
            MsgBox("Cut File already exists, nothing copied.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Design Dock")
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(subd.FullName & "\BLANK.CMD")


        End Try
    Else


        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

may this help you

```
System.IO.File.Copy( "SO123456.zip", "temp\SO123456.zip" )
' same for other files you dont need to remove it


Dim strDirectory As String = " C:\epds\WIP\"
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(strDirectory, "*.*")
   My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(foundFile, FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.DeletePermanently)
Next

System.IO.File.Copy( "SO123456.zip", "C:\epds\WIP\SO123456.zip" )
' same for other files you dont need to remove it
```